# Why does method validation not work in tests?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, kotlin

I have a problem, I don't know how to test a method in my controller.

Method:

```
@PatchMapping("{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
fun edit(@PathVariable id: Long, @Valid @RequestBody baseData: EditOrganizationRequest?) =
    manageOrganizationService.update(id, baseData!!).let {
        EntityModel.of(it)
    }
```

Test:

```
@Test
fun `#edit should return 'bad request' error`() {
    val emptyDataRequest = EditOrganizationRequest("")

    mvc.patch("/organizations/1") {
        contentType = APPLICATION_JSON
        content = asJsonString(emptyDataRequest)
    }.andExpect {
        status { isBadRequest() }
    }
}
```

A created by me test doesn't work. I get: `Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content must not be null!`. This exception is thrown because validation doesn't prevent a run service method.

If I make a request via Postman I never get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with a test case.